# php form upload via permission 777, permissions 755 suphp, or ftp?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Looking for opinions on which is the best?

Upload through form to a 777 directory.

Upload through form to a 775 directory using suphp.

Upload through form to a directory using ftp.

-- File through ftp example-- this way the folder doesnt have to be write for apache; more secure

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file'], 'r');
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: How can you even upload through a form using FTP?

Comment: Pass the file over to php and ftp server side

Answer (score 0):

You should be uploading a file to a directory that Apache has write permissions on, not everybody on the internet. Apache should have write permissions by default on most shared hosting services.

If you have your own server there are several command lines you can run to give apache write permissions to your upload directories. I'm not going to go into any specific ones since it varies by operating system.

As for the actual uploading you want to submit a file as part of a form to a script. I'm going to use php:

```
$file = $_FILES["get/post name"]; <- Will get you the file
move_uploaded_file($file, "wherever/you/want/"); <- moves tmp file to directory of your choice. You should do this relative to your document root.
```

don't forget the last / or it will put the file in the 'you' folder with the name want(yourname).extension